# Как спроектировать базу данных для веб страниц каталогов?

Tags: база-данных

есть таблица **product** (id, brand_id, ...) - товар
есть таблица **category** (id, ...) - категория товара
есть связующая таблица **category_product** (product_id, category_id)
есть таблица **brand** (id, ...) - производитель товара

на сайте нужны страницы подобного содержания:

```
/catalog/{category}/ - каталог товаров по виду
/product/{product} - карточка товара
/brand/{brand}/ - каталог товаров по бренду
/catalog/{brand}-{category}/ - каталог товаров по бренду и по виду
/catalog/{special_products}/ - каталог товаров с выборкой по какому-либо признаку товара
```

Пример:

```
/product/gucci-kurtka-chernaya-0123 - карточка черной куртки бренда gucci артикул 0123
/brand/gucci/ - каталог товаров gucci
/catalog/gucci-kurtki/ - каталог курток gucci
/catalog/kurtki/ - каталог всех курток
/catalog/kurtki-chernye/ - каталог только черных курток
```

Думаю отделить такие вещи, как активность, h1, title, description от товаров/категорий, соответственно сделать отдельные таблицы для веб-страниц, но не знаю как правильно все связать, особенно для страниц с выборкой из нескольких раных таблиц (куртки гучи, черные куртки гучи итп).

В голову приходит вариант сделать одну таблицу **page** с необходимыми полями и связать с товарами таблицей **page_product**, но не представляю как это все тогда сгруппировать и сделать иерархии, сделать тегированные страницы (что-бы в куртках были ссылки на страницы красных курток, черных курток, курток гучи, и все что тоже "куртки"), наверно это по-другому решается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это спроектировать?

Comment: Не усложняйте задачу, а наоборот упрощяйте. Обычно в таких случаях проектируют базу, всю необходимую информацию добавляют по мере усложнения. Хочу так - добавили туда, хочу вот так-лобавили сюда

Comment: @AzizUmarov, не согласен. Тут есть довольно красивое решение, а при добавлении куда попало будет комплект костылей.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не говорю что истина в моих устах. Я говорю что мне не попадался такой проект и такую задачу я решаю по другому

Comment: @AzizUmarov, если есть какое-то предложение, было бы неплохо сформировать из него ответ и запостить. А фраза про постепенное усложнение применима к 90% agile-разработки чего угодно.

Answer (score 1):

- Делаешь отдельно набор тегов: `гучи`, `чёрный`, `куртка` и так далее.
- Через отдельную таблицу организуешь связь многие-ко многим для тегов и товаров.
- Каким-то образом составляешь или генерируешь словарь, ставящий в соответствие страницу и набор тегов.
- При открытии страницы берёшь соответствующие ей теги и выгружаешь все товары по ним.
- При необходимости можно усложнить, заменив один из тегов (`куртка`) на категорию, чтобы в рамках категории показывать определённый набор характеристик. Тогда у страницы может быть только одна категория и произвольное число тегов.

Comment: А что тут написано нового. Декомпозиция задачи и усложнение по мере поступления новых задач.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, нового по сравнению с чем? С вопросом - вроде всё новое. С комментарием? В нём недостаточно конкретики, чтобы что-то сделать. А где здесь усложнение по мере поступления новых задач, я вообще не понял. Я его понимал как добавление колонок, а не тегов.

Comment: это ведь не отличается от приведенного примера с **page** и **page_product**? Т.е. насоздавать страниц по всяким тегам, прописать там title description итп, связать каждую страницу с товарами и только их выводить в веб, а все остальное иммутабельно?
Я так думаю и иерархию там еще надо делать, ссылку на родительскую страницу, но не сложно ли будет синхронизировать изменения в основых таблицах?

Comment: @VicTHOR, нет, совершенно разные вещи. Я не связываю страницу с товарами напрямую вообще. Теги постоянны, а товары меняются.

Comment: @Qwertiy, "При открытии страницы берёшь соответствующие ей теги и выгружаешь все товары по ним" - а где хранить веб свойства к получившемся страницам и чем это все-таки отличается, если **page_product** - таблица связей "страниц" и "товаров", которые могут меняться точно так же... Разница в том, что в случае тегов будет только 1 тег в строке? Но как с этим работать? И как вложенности на сайте сделать тогда?
Вопрос про синхронизацию был не о товарах, а, например, бренд какой-то удалили/переименовали, а тег все тот же, и с каталогом так же... Эти данные приходят из 1С